# Best practices to update a live web service

Tags: web-services

I am always curious about how large-scale live web application updates are done. Since the application is live, that is why it complicates everything -you should not down your service and at the same time you should recover the activity/changes (in database etc.) made on your site to the new version during the update later on.

The first and most natural technique comes to the mind is that redirecting all the requests to some other replicated server, so that you can update original server without shutting-down your service.

I just wonder is there any other smarter techniques to handle updates in a live web service. Please, share your experience and opinions guys!

Answer (score 0):

I am facing the same challenge myself.

What i did was to recreate the web page on another server [lets name it Test server] (with a different domain of course), import the scripts/database from live server and adjust them on the new domain.

Now I am experimenting on the Test server and after i make sure that everything is working OK, i am pushing the changes to the live server.

Unfortunately, i dont know if this is the correct way to do this. You have to be careful but it works.